# Cannot install the network driver in my toshiba L745-S4210

Tags: drivers

have tried installing 3 differentt drivers already, in order to solve a wireless network connection problemin my laptop toshiba satellite L745-S4210.
My computer shows the message "no connections are available." I press troubleshoot, and then i get the next message:

"Windows did not detect a properly installed network adapter. If you have a network adapter, you will need to reinstall the driver."

I have tried installing the Toshiba Applications and Drivers Patch,
I have also tried installing the Realtek Wireless LAN Driver, and the Intel Wireless LAN Driver.

In what could i be wrong, or what else can I try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help if you knew the actual wireless chipset: [How to identify the built-in wireless lan card and the installed driver version with the Toshiba PC diagnostic tool.](http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD16036E0000R01.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you need to ensure your wifi is enabled ... you can do this by hitting the windows button and searching for "network connections".... right clicking on the wifi adapter and select enable... or there may be a wifi button on the laptop itself ... looks like thats "fn+F8" this will toggle the wifi card on and off..

Also, is there wifi network available where you are? you can check that with another device.. smart phones are a good judge